# dc.js getting a total for dimensions

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Fairly new to both javascript and dc so hopefully someone can point out a glaring mistake in here if one is obvious.

So the data I'm working with is in json format. It details the greenhouse gas emissions in kilotons from road transport between the years 1990 and 2016:

```
[
{
"1990": 69593.92909,
"1991": 68925.18017,
"1992": 69568.94507,
"1993": 69195.74371,
"1994": 66808.01905,
"1995": 64783.39396,
"1996": 66260.2817,
"1997": 65966.62162,
"1998": 64867.48598,
"1999": 65179.13673,
"2000": 64344.87089,
"2001": 63143.60193,
"2002": 62912.45843,
"2003": 60191.471,
"2004": 58955.982,
"2005": 56986.74396,
"2006": 54508.46013,
"2007": 52975.47679,
"2008": 49592.26223,
"2009": 46777.43559,
"2010": 43660.39487,
"2011": 41442.9064,
"2012": 39430.83139,
"2013": 37416.43375,
"2014": 36589.0465,
"2015": 35781.24439,
"2016": 35349.0576,
"Source": "Cars - Petrol"
},
{
"1990": 3148.096056,
"1991": 3559.279418,
"1992": 4501.543401,
"1993": 5763.746164,
"1994": 7551.451743,
"1995": 8839.059026,
"1996": 10165.98148,
"1997": 11134.32811,
"1998": 11490.2288,
"1999": 12563.88218,
"2000": 13115.085,
"2001": 14155.22918,
"2002": 15869.5177,
"2003": 17287.36108,
"2004": 18968.56143,
"2005": 20870.68665,
"2006": 22828.90392,
"2007": 24638.45712,
"2008": 25697.25635,
"2009": 26184.72538,
"2010": 27064.5961,
"2011": 28505.71289,
"2012": 30195.3133,
"2013": 31042.51841,
"2014": 32126.20481,
"2015": 33455.19565,
"2016": 35354.85215,
"Source": "Cars - Diesel"
 },
 {
"1990": 7320.552186,
"1991": 7093.082751,
"1992": 6637.212661,
"1993": 6243.982502,
"1994": 5764.001438,
"1995": 5117.0386,
"1996": 4848.336446,
"1997": 4508.602099,
"1998": 4226.296125,
"1999": 3582.015194,
"2000": 3104.684909,
"2001": 2647.70305,
"2002": 2270.02413,
"2003": 1949.951969,
"2004": 1731.534116,
"2005": 1498.096445,
"2006": 1489.266001,
"2007": 1377.155724,
"2008": 1239.89787,
"2009": 1086.068122,
"2010": 978.3437778,
"2011": 901.571409,
"2012": 823.0520605,
"2013": 768.0300208,
"2014": 727.6683437,
"2015": 683.7916969,
"2016": 649.8161786,
"Source": "LGVs - Petrol"
},
{
"1990": 4380.373876,
"1991": 5001.759915,
"1992": 5589.825615,
"1993": 6187.067679,
"1994": 7192.852571,
"1995": 7853.696941,
"1996": 8756.823494,
"1997": 9670.809673,
"1998": 10210.54947,
"1999": 10788.81777,
"2000": 11249.3556,
"2001": 11733.90808,
"2002": 12320.65248,
"2003": 13067.11867,
"2004": 13756.55654,
"2005": 14428.76742,
"2006": 14858.27928,
"2007": 15573.87491,
"2008": 14821.01165,
"2009": 14722.3269,
"2010": 15169.77151,
"2011": 15348.7601,
"2012": 15590.40271,
"2013": 15857.02735,
"2014": 16626.16906,
"2015": 17523.01445,
"2016": 18567.29094,
"Source": "LGVs - Diesel"
},
{
"1990": 5339.157087,
"1991": 5467.466971,
"1992": 5392.960065,
"1993": 5377.750567,
"1994": 5440.415776,
"1995": 5508.010587,
"1996": 5568.965398,
"1997": 5566.064477,
"1998": 5432.401344,
"1999": 5241.387095,
"2000": 4912.219975,
"2001": 4801.21838,
"2002": 4773.64816,
"2003": 4883.157328,
"2004": 4681.323432,
"2005": 4673.478741,
"2006": 4728.510847,
"2007": 4870.561051,
"2008": 4246.393859,
"2009": 4237.468976,
"2010": 4331.09672,
"2011": 3995.306943,
"2012": 3819.356001,
"2013": 3872.42702,
"2014": 3858.306896,
"2015": 3733.342863,
"2016": 3491.547872,
"Source": "Buses and Coaches"
},
{
"1990": 20549.84591,
"1991": 19538.54867,
"1992": 19457.03083,
"1993": 19730.14005,
"1994": 20340.94429,
"1995": 20004.24193,
"1996": 20573.1718,
"1997": 20611.02009,
"1998": 20393.29457,
"1999": 19989.60494,
"2000": 19665.41352,
"2001": 19642.46875,
"2002": 20113.67776,
"2003": 20299.40457,
"2004": 20701.27394,
"2005": 20956.01743,
"2006": 20975.16199,
"2007": 21128.61243,
"2008": 19650.07428,
"2009": 18115.9976,
"2010": 18661.96818,
"2011": 18236.36235,
"2012": 18286.93244,
"2013": 18381.82839,
"2014": 18909.17826,
"2015": 19931.43374,
"2016": 20360.34154,
"Source": "HGV"
},
{
"1990": 727.5617999,
"1991": 710.4634975,
"1992": 609.4520657,
"1993": 519.774719,
"1994": 509.2231228,
"1995": 503.1006123,
"1996": 525.6073905,
"1997": 568.1948702,
"1998": 585.0268566,
"1999": 646.6997447,
"2000": 641.3058103,
"2001": 652.2754823,
"2002": 681.564717,
"2003": 741.4856181,
"2004": 679.5842972,
"2005": 710.8353572,
"2006": 662.6894662,
"2007": 704.5256474,
"2008": 649.562263,
"2009": 636.8283738,
"2010": 561.0698798,
"2011": 557.3736257,
"2012": 531.1360981,
"2013": 504.6618709,
"2014": 519.1426045,
"2015": 524.409001,
"2016": 544.3244057,
"Source": "Motorcycles - >50 cc"
},
{
"1990": 68.18440893,
"1991": 61.90839807,
"1992": 51.38951192,
"1993": 41.13160339,
"1994": 39.39956559,
"1995": 34.87192636,
"1996": 32.59435156,
"1997": 30.99510927,
"1998": 30.56930476,
"1999": 33.9429331,
"2000": 35.40654479,
"2001": 36.54028425,
"2002": 35.25401917,
"2003": 36.87676555,
"2004": 30.94174336,
"2005": 30.78605235,
"2006": 25.91880501,
"2007": 27.52053808,
"2008": 22.41888214,
"2009": 21.07530165,
"2010": 18.32310824,
"2011": 17.17460528,
"2012": 15.6090557,
"2013": 13.14104882,
"2014": 12.30089753,
"2015": 11.32364855,
"2016": 10.97048206,
"Source": "Mopeds - <50cc"
},
{
"1990": 0,
"1991": 0,
"1992": 0,
"1993": 0,
"1994": 0,
"1995": 0,
"1996": 2.970725709,
"1997": 5.941451418,
"1998": 11.97029772,
"1999": 23.93656381,
"2000": 65.61233439,
"2001": 160.465194,
"2002": 258.3156443,
"2003": 311.1751708,
"2004": 332.7632485,
"2005": 358.2895797,
"2006": 374.6397872,
"2007": 353.3743875,
"2008": 369.0592288,
"2009": 316.9182002,
"2010": 314.7224273,
"2011": 290.7193995,
"2012": 274.9473235,
"2013": 277.6184974,
"2014": 259.730796,
"2015": 241.8100066,
"2016": 209.0667968,
"Source": "All LPG Vehicles"
}
]
```

I am able to render a chart with the different sources of emissions (e.g. Cars - Petrol, Cars - Diesel etc.) on the x axis and the numerical value for a year on the y axis. So for example, the emissions data for the year 1990 would be rendered:

```
function makeGraph(error, ggData) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var ndx = crossfilter(ggData); //load the data into a crossfilter

    var sourceDim = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck("Source"));
    var sourceDimGroup = sourceDim.group();

    y1990Emissions(ndx);

    dc.renderAll();

    //generate x axis source and y axis kilotonnes for year 1990
    function y1990Emissions(ndx) {
        var y1990 = sourceDim.group().reduceSum(dc.pluck("1990")); //the y axis

        dc.barChart("#y1990-pollution")
            .width(700)
            .height(500)
            .margins({top:10, right:50, bottom: 100, left:50})
            .dimension(sourceDim)
            .group(y1990)
            .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
            .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal);
    };
};
```

However, I'm at a loss as to how I can generate a bar chart for the TOTAL emissions data from all sources along the y axis, with the different years along the x axis. 
[Something that looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoMx1.png)

I feel like I need to use a counter variable, and so far I have this

```
function totalEmissionsPerYear(ndx) {
var total1990 = 0;
var total1990Dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { 
    return total1990 += d["1990"]; 
});
```

But I'm not really sure where to take it from there.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a format you'll be able to do much cross-filtering with. If you're open to transforming your data to a different shape, such as a single array of triplets `{source, year, amount}` it will be a lot easier to work with crossfilter & dc.js.

Comment: Yeah i was suspecting my data isn't formatted in a way that's optimised for crossfilter, there's no reason I can't reformat my data however. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: That's great. Crossfilter definitely prefers a flat array of records. Just shout if you run into other problems!

Comment: So reformatting the data worked. You just cured a big headache of mine, many thanks!